# The method is not allowed for the requested URL: Using Flask POST Method

Tags: python, numpy, flask

First of all, I am very new to this so I hope I can explain myself the best I can.
I have a project in college in which we are using Flask to create a web app.

We need to gather inputs from users and then predict certain values with a model I have created, saved with Pickle and load it in my app .Now when I access to my page , I can see the home page shows and I am able to enter inputs but then the 'predict' page is not showing and giving me the error ***'The method is not allowed for the requested URL'***. I have consulted and follow different approaches to do this, for example from this article: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/10/easily-deploy-machine-learning-models-using-flask.html and this https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-a-machine-learning-model-using-flask-da580f84e60c but still not able to make it work.

Any help, tips or good tutorials would be so much appreciated! Thank you so much in advance and sorry for this long post.

My project folder has the following contents:

- app.py
- model.pkl(This is my model saved on my disk using Pickle)
- Powerproduction dataset.csv( the original dataset)
- request.py
- model.py ( this is the model )

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
   def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
   def predict():
       int_features = [float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
       final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
       prediction = model.predict(final_features)
       output = round(prediction[0], 2)
       return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Power output should be $ {}'.format(output))
@app.route('/results',methods=['POST'])
    def results():
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        prediction = model.predict(final_features)

        output = prediction[0]
        return jsonify(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug=True)`
```

```
    import requests

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
    r = requests.post(url,json={'wind speed':})

    print(r.json())
```

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import pickle

    dataset = pd.read_csv('Powerproduction dataset.csv')

    X = dataset.loc['speed']

    y = dataset.loc['power']

    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    regressor = LinearRegression()

    regressor.fit(X.values.reshape(-1,1), y)

    pickle.dump(regressor, open('model.pkl','wb'))

    model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
    print(model.predict(np.array([[34.00]]))[0])
```

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Wind speed and power output prediction</title> 
</head>

<body style="background: #000;">
    <h1>Power output predictions</h1>

     <!-- Main Input For Receiving Query to our ML -->
    <form action="{{ url_for('home')}}"method="post">
        < />
        <input type="text" name="wind speed" placeholder="wind speed" required="required" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict power output</button>
    </form>

   <br>
   <br>
   {{ prediction_text }}

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the index.html file which I have in templates folder. The code here:

Comment: Are you calling `/predict` URL using `GET` method?

Comment: Please add the `index.html` to the Question

Comment: @SameerNaik I did not know I needed that, as you see I am very new to this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Heythere_ Here is a detailed guide on making good questions on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I added the index.html code  also at the end of the question the question for reference @HarshanaSerasinghe .Thank you

Comment: @Heythere_ I'll have to give you credit for how you're approaching and handling this. If everyone who asked questions would follow your example, questions would be far easier to answer.

Comment: @SameerNaik what I am trying to do is to get inputs using the index.html , and then this input goes to the app.py file to be handle there. The request.py is going to request app.py for the predictions.  I need a response with the last route (/result) that computes the prediction value ( which is calculated with my model that was loaded into this file also as "model.pkl".

Comment: Then using  jsonify I wanted to show the output it as JSON . As a summary what I basically  need is to get an input ( a number), made the code process it and calculate a prediction based on my model ( which works) and show that in '/results' page. As simple as possible as I just need to do this to submit my project. If there is a way easier and simpler way to do this using one app only or anything I am all ears! I hope this clarifies. Thanks a million. @lukas thanks so much I am having a look into the guidelines and I will tidy my post. Happy new year to everyone  in the meantime!

Answer (score 1):

Your action references your `home` route:

```
action="{{ url_for('home')}}
```

You want this to point to your `predict` route:

```
action="{{ url_for('predict') }}"
```

You should also have a space after `"` (but most browsers parse this correctly):

```
action="{{ url_for('predict') }}" method="post">
```

The empty `< />` in your `index.html` should also be removed.

I'd also fix the indentation, usually you don't indent after `@app.route(..)` and make sure you have an empty line between function end and your next route to make it more readable (there is a standard named PEP-8 that defines how Python code should look - Pycharm and other editors will usually give you hints if you don't conform):

```
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    ..

@app.route(...)
def foo():
    ..
```